# Pyvis and Networkx: How to make nodes different color based on source or target

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, networkx, pyvis

I've strung together a few answers from SO and got this far but can't get nodes to show different colors.  My code is attempting to get Team nodes to be Red while State nodes are Black.  But eventually I'd like to have node colors defined in the source file via the Type attribute (nfl=red, nba=black, mlb=green).  Appreciate any help.

Source file csv:

```
team,state,Weight,type
Knicks,New York,9,nba
Warriors,California,9,nba
Giants,California,3,mlb
49ers,California,6,nfl
Cowboys,Texas,1,nfl
Giants,New York,2,nfl
```

Code:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from pyvis.network import Network

df = pd.read_csv('./data_files/sample.csv')

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,
                            source='team',
                            target='state',
                            edge_attr='Weight')

colors = []

for node in G:
    if node in df["team"].values:
        colors.append("red")
    else: 
        colors.append("black")

print(colors)

nx.draw(G, node_color=colors, with_labels=True)

net = Network(notebook=True, filter_menu=True, cdn_resources='remote')

net.from_nx(G)

net.show("./output/teams.html")
```

Comment: Your phrasing is a bit confusing. Initially, you say that all the teams and states should have a unique color each (*red or black*) and then you say that the colors of the nodes should be calculated based on the type, giving three colors (*red, black or green*). Can you clarify that, please ?

Comment: Hi @Timeless, sorry for the confusion.  My code is attempting to define color by team/states but that's just me trying to understand how to apply colors.  My end goal is to be able to define node colors by the type.

Comment: No worries and thanks for the clarification. So `Knicks` and `New York` should be *black* ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  Oh I see the conflict.  Cause New York will need to be Red per the last row.  Can you show me how to color only the team node per the Type?

Comment: And how do you want to color the states ?

Comment: I guess just leave them at a default color, blue or something.  As I learn more, my entire solution may change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to conditionally color one of the nodes based on `type`, you can make a [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) :

```
default = "blue"

colors = dict(nfl="red", nba="black", mlb="green")

dmap = df.set_index("team")["type"].map(colors).to_dict()

nx.draw(G, node_color=[dmap.get(n, default) for n in G.nodes], with_labels=True)
```

NB : If the nodes are *unique*, you can map both columns together, this way :

```
dmap = (pd.lreshape(df, {"nodes": ["team", "state"]})
     .set_index("nodes")["type"].map(colors).to_dict())
```

If you need to set the colors as attributes before saving an html, you can use :

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, dmap, "color") # << add this line

net.from_nx(G)

net.write_html("./output/teams.html")
```

Preview (*of teams.html*):

[image]

Comment: **NB**: You have duplicated nodes per row. For example `Giants` has two types (mlb-green and nfl-red). So, only the last color will be chosen. If you can define how to deal with this configuration, I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the example and screen shot @Timeless.  I'm not getting the different colors, or neither did I get colors using the other SO examples.  This is what I see when rendered via the html on chrome browser - https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXd9N.png

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer to address that. Can you check it, please ?

Comment: Yay it's working, you're the man (or woman) @Timeless.  Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short solution using [gravis](https://robert-haas.github.io/gravis-docs) to create the graph visualization you requested. Source node colors are determined by the `type` column, and edge widths come from the `Weight` column in your DataFrame.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of gravis and provide this answer because use cases like yours were part of the motivation to build this package and therefore it is straightforward to generate a fitting solution with it.

```
import gravis as gv
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./data_files/sample.csv')
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='team', target='state', edge_attr=('Weight', 'type'))
mapping = dict(nfl='red', nba='black', mlb='green')
for (source, target), attr in graph.edges.items():
    graph.nodes[source]['color'] = mapping[attr['type']]
    graph.edges[(source, target)]['size'] = attr['Weight'] / 2

fig = gv.d3(graph)
fig.display()  # opens a web browser with the visualization
```

Instead of `fig.display()` you can also use `fig.export_html(filename)` to create a standalone HTML file, or `fig.to_html()` to get HTML text you can serve in a web app. If you like Jupyter notebooks, you can also embed the visualization in the output cell:
[image]